# Grails RadioGroup, how to bind labels to radio name

Tags: grails, radio-button, label, gsp, radio-group

I'm struggling arround with the `g:radioGroup` tag -- I want to create some radios and some labels correspondig to the radios:

```
<g:radioGroup name="stateOfHealth" value="${review.stateOfHealth}" id="stammp"
        labels="['1','2','3','4','5']"
        values="['bad','suboptimal','well','veryWell','excellent']">
    <span class="radioSpan"> ${it.radio}</span>
    <label for="${ ???? }">${it.label}</label>
</g:radioGroup>
```

What do I need to do to insert in the label's "for" attribute to match the right radio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to set the for attribute, just wrap the radio with the label, like this:

```
<g:radioGroup name="stateOfHealth" value="${review.stateOfHealth}" id="stammp"
        labels="['1','2','3','4','5']"
        values="['bad','suboptimal','well','veryWell','excellent']">

    <label>
            <span class="radioSpan">${it.radio}</span>
            ${it.label}
    </label>

</g:radioGroup>
```

Comment: this just renders the label text in no tags this is how i came to this question

Comment: No, in this case the `label` tag is wrapping the radio, so you don't need to set the `for` attribute. If you try, you'll see that when you click a label the appropriate radio box will check.

Comment: haha sorryy i didn´t realized your label tags, thanks a lot this woorks awesome